# SQL How to get columns from other tables based on other columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to get values like

`AdviserInit, AdviserSurname, MaterialName and Area` using `AdviserID, MaterialID and AreaCode` from `Chores Table` as my reference.

I don't know what will be my approach in creating the query. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
 SELECT Chores.ChoresID, Chores.ChoresDate, Materials.MaterialName,
        Advisers.AdviserInit,     Advisers.AdviserSurname, Area.Area,
        Chores.StudentID     
 FROM Chores INNER JOIN Materials on Chores.MaterialID = Materials.MaterialID     
      INNER JOIN Advisers on Chores.AdviserID = Advisers.AdviserID     
      INNER JOIN Area on Chores.AreaCode = Area.AreaCode
```

Here's the screenshot of the relationships between the tables:

[image: Table relationships]

Comment: Jeremy, why don't you improve your question by posting full descriptions of your tables and describing the contents of each and the relationships between them?  As it stands, your question is unanswerable (we don't have nearly enough information) and already in danger of being closed. Sample data (anonymized, if necessary) from each table would be helpful as well.

Comment: Ok Sir, I was about to post the screenshot of the table relationships but I was denied, I'm going to post the picture from an external source. I'm sorry for that

Comment: @Jeremy see sample query within posted answer

Comment: @Piyush I can't see if the query is working, because I'm using Visual Basic 6 and I'm getting an error "Syntax error (missing operator) on query expression"

Comment: you are using sql server?

Comment: @Jeremy, this query I tested on sqlfiddle, and this is working fine, may be some issue in your code while executing this query

Comment: @Piyush I'm using Access, thank you very much I'll just check if my syntax is correct.

Comment: I update the sql query based on Ms-access syntax, now its using parentheses

Comment: I've already figured it out, thank you, the query is now working fine

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query, if you want to map all tables with main Chores Table,

```
SELECT Chores.ChoresID, Chores.ChoresDate, Materials.MaterialName,
       Advisers.AdviserInit,Advisers.AdviserSurname, Area.Area,
       Chores.StudentNo, Student.Forename    
FROM (((Chores INNER JOIN Materials on Chores.MaterialID = Materials.MaterialID)     
     INNER JOIN Advisers on Chores.AdviserID = Advisers.AdviserID)     
     INNER JOIN Area on Chores.AreaCode = Area.AreaCode)
     INNER JOIN Student on Student.StudentNo =  Chores.StudentNo
```

The placement of the parentheses is important here. Basically, you need to have n - 2 left parentheses after the `from` clause and one right parenthesis before the start of each new `join clause` except for the first, where n is the number of `tables` being `joined` together.

The reason is that Access's join syntax supports joining only two tables at a time, so if you need to join more than two you need to enclose the extra ones in parentheses.